# How to write a specific aggregate query using Mongo?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a collection of documents which are stored in the following format:

```
{
     '_id': 'bdfc0e7a-720d-49d5-86e4-bce4056b334f',
     'agent_id': '69717061b28611e29c6410ddb1b42209',
     'campaign_id': 'huts1371065967012',
     'data': None,
     'metric': 'SESSION_START',
     'screen_id': 'piece',
     'session_id': '57753353-8cfe-4f6d-88bd-ecfef65b5afd',
     'timestamp': 1352947632.59
}
```

I want to be able to use the aggregation framework to pull data grouped first by the metric key and secondly by different time/date ranges using the timestamp key based on a user selection. The user will be allowed to group by hour, day, week or month...

The goal is to get a count of the individual metric broken down by which ever time grouping the user selects (hour, day, week, month). For this I guess I'm going to have to convert the timestamp key from floating point to a date object of some kind to be able to accomplish this?

An example of the result of the aggregation I'd like to see (in this particular exmaple grouped hourly):

```
{
     'ok': 1.0,
     'result': [
          {
               '_id': 'SESSION_START_1/1/2013_00',
               'metric': 'SESSION_START',
               'count': 34,
               'timeframe': '1/1/2013 00'
          },
          {
               '_id': 'SESSION_START_1/1/2013_01',
               'metric': 'SESSION_START',
               'count': 15,
               'timeframe': '1/1/2013 01'
          },...
     ]
}
```

Is there any easy way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Could you include what you've tried so far? If you work through the steps, aggregations are not too hard. The timestamp is likely to be a problem though. You might need to use MapReduce.

Comment: I haven't tried anything because I'm not sure where to start with the timestamp issue. If I could get that squared away I think I'd be able to do this on my own.

Comment: You might want to take a look at this: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/mongodb-user/J3cwu3oiN2A as it's a reasonable solution to doing some math operations. Although, it's still not going to be straightforward with aggregation to get it into the format you want. Is storing the timestamp in a different format an option?

Comment: Yeah, I think I'm going to end up storing it as ISODate so that I then would be able to group using the $year, $month, $dayOfMonth, $hour built in aggregate functions.

Comment: actually you don't have to change the schema.  I just posted an answer to exactly the same question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17299190/mongodb-aggregation-framework-and-timestamp  his is specifically by month by it can easily be extended to other time slices.