# Mongodb Aggregation Framework and timestamp

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a collection

```
{ "_id" : 1325376000, "value" : 13393}
{ "_id" : 1325462400, "value" : 13393}
```

ObjectIds are Unix Timestamp and are storing as Number manually.(at insert time).

now I'm searching for a solution that i could calculate sum of values for each month with Aggregation Framework.

Comment: You'd need to change your `_id` values to be `Date` objects instead of numbers.

Comment: Docs per @JohnnyHK comment:  http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/#date-operators

Comment: using date type instead of timestump is expensive.

Comment: Do you know the date range into which these timestamps fall?  I.e. is it last 6 months worth, last 2 years worth, etc?

Comment: No. 'values'  are from a sensor every minutes and system is going to work years. I want minimum monthly averages.

Comment: do you want minimum or average? your original question asks for sum, and now you say minimum and average - which is it?  anyway see my answer - it caters to all of them, and you can compute $avg, $sum, $min whatever.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way you can do it by generating the aggregation pipeline programmatically:

```
numberOfMonths=24;   /* number of months you want to go back from today's */
now=new Date();
year=now.getFullYear();
mo=now.getMonth();
months=[];
for (i=0;i<numberOfMonths;i++) {
      m1=mo-i+1; m2=m1-1;
      d = new Date(year,m1,1); 
      d2=new Date(year,m2,1);
      from= d2.getTime()/1000; 
      to= d.getTime()/1000;
      dt={from:from, to:to, month:d2};  months.push(dt); 
}
prev="$nothing";
cond={};
months.forEach(function(m) { 
      cond={$cond: [{$and :[ {$gte:["$_id",m.from]}, {$lt:["$_id",m.to]}  ]}, m.month, prev]}; 
      prev=cond; 
} );

/* now you can use "cond" variable in your pipeline to generate month */
db.collection.aggregate( { $project: { month: cond , value:1 } }, 
                         { $group: {_id:"$month", sum:{$sum:"$value"} } }
)
```

Comment: obviously you can add {$sort} after the group, you can also compute $avg or $min or anything else if $sum is not what you want.